# changed default store for website - now some products do not work properly anymore

Tags: magento2, multistore, visibility

Assume we have one website and we have two stores for that website: `StoreA` and `StoreB`, plus a store view for each store of course, `StoreA_view` and `StoreB_view`. **The default store for the website was configured to be** `StoreA`.

Assume we have some products who were configured to be enabled in `StoreB_view`, but not in `StoreA_view`.

Now we changed the default store of the website to `StoreB` instead. Everything works fine - except for the products that should only be visible in `StoreB_view` and not `StoreA_view`.

The products can be found in `StoreB_view` just fine. They can also be added to the cart. However, when opening the cart, the items are not actually there. The cart will be empty - even though the cart sum will show, that *one* of those products is in fact in the cart. It's rather odd.

Is there anything that needs to be done after changing the default store of a website, regarding the products and their visibility? We already did a complete `indexer:reindex` - however that had no effect.

Magento version: 2.2.8

Comment: "who were configured to be enabled in StoreB, but not in StoreA" how? enabled scope is website

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Products can be enabled and disabled in the store view scope as well.

Comment: I edited the question, so that it is more clear regarding websites, stores and store views.

Comment: the "enabled" setting has it's scope on website. how exactly did you enabled/disable product for a store

Comment: @PhilippSander just edit a product, select the store view, deselect _Default value_ for the __Enable Product__ setting, disable the __Enable Product__ setting.

Comment: do you see the [website] under the label? that's the scope... if you toogle it you will change the setting for all stores and store-views within the website

Comment: Yes, but you can still override it on a store view level by disabling _Default value_.

Comment: Just to clarify, here are two screenshots, showing the configuration of a product on the store view level: https://imgur.com/a/jLV3xiQ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92863/discussion-between-philipp-sander-and-fritzmg).

Comment: see my recorded demo https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylTv2.gif

Comment: what you described is no default magento behavior! If you changed this you must provided us more context.